# addReply method not working showing error System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: unit-test, controller

```
public class eController {
    public List < e_Message__c > lrMsg {
        get {
            return lstPrMsg != null ? lrMsg : new list < e__c > ();
        }
        set;
    }


    public eController() {
                public void addReply() {

        ;
        msg.Message_To__c = parentMsg.Message_From__c;
    }
}
```

Comment: is parentId null?

Comment: objPMC.parentId = 'a0N36000002g12q';   You need to query to get this value of parentid. Or rather you need to create the parent record and then query for it and assign to parentid. In Test class you dont have access to existing records you would need to create records in your test class. If you really need to use existing records then you would need to use SeeAllData= true. Though using this is not recomended

Comment: Correct @Prady.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
objPMC.parentId = 'a0N36000002g12q';
```

You need to query to get this value of parentid. Or rather you need to create the parent record and then query for it and assign to parentid. In Test class you dont have access to existing records you would need to create records in your test class. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm

> Whenever possible, you should create test data for each test. You can
>   disable this restriction by annotating your test class or test method
>   with the IsTest(SeeAllData=true) annotation.

If you really need to use existing records then you would need to use SeeAllData= true. Though using this is not recommended